# Cannot import caffe - iPython doesn't find environment variables that 'ordinary' python finds

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I'm using Anaconda python on a Mac running OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

I'm trying to use `pycaffe` in iPython, but importing it (`import caffe`) fails with the error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../Documents/caffe-master/python/caffe/_caffe.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/.../Documents/caffe-master/python/caffe/_caffe.so
  Reason: image not found
```

While iPython can't import caffe, doing so in 'ordinary' python works.

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import caffe
>>> caffe.Net
<class 'caffe._caffe.Net'>
```

I should also mention that I'm using CUDA 7.5, and although I can't see which version of caffe I have (downloaded zip) it was done from the master branch on September 17 2015.

The actions I took for 'ordinary' python to be able to import caffe was to add the following to ~/.bash_profile

```
# added pycaffe path
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/.../Documents/caffe-master/python:$PYTHONPATH"

# needed to import pycaffe in python
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/cuda/lib:/anaconda/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/intel/lib:/opt/intel/mkl/lib'
```

iPython is reading the PYTHONPATH set in `.bash_profile` since it will give `ImportError: No module named caffe` if the `export PYTHONPATH=...` line is commented out. But for some reason it doesn't find the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, which 'ordinary' python does.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that the main issue was that due to the new feature called SIP (System Integrity Protection) in El Capitan, that prevents `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` from being set. This is a feature that is supposed to provide extra protection against root attacks on Mac OSX.

To disable SIP:

- Restart computer in recovery mode by holding in cmd-R when starting
  up.
- Open a terminal window (under Utilities in the top menu).
- Enter `csrutil disable` to turn SIP off (and `csrutil enable` to turn it back on).
- Restart computer from Apple symbol in the manu.

This solved the issue for me. For more info: [MacWorld article on SIP](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html), [Caffe user mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/waugt62RQMU).